# Jasig CAS Proxy Ticket For special target URL

Tags: java, proxy, cas, jasig

I need to generate a Proxy Tiket using the CAS client API for a target URl like this: https://host.com/wms**
The special characters ** are necessary because the request can attach after the proxy ticket generation some parameters. 
It is possible to do this or it is manatory to use the strictly target url rappresentation?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Proxy Tickets, you must use the complete representation.  It does not take wild cards.  That said, you should be able to specify the target url at runtime (i.e. if you generate it during the request). The only requirement is that the target used when generating the PT is the same target value used to validate it.

```
targetService [REQUIRED] - the service identifier of the back-end service. Note that not all back-end services are web services so this service identifier will not always be a URL. However, the service identifier specified here MUST match the "service" parameter specified to /proxyValidate upon validation of the proxy ticket.
```

source: http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol